# How to convert `extern int getchar (void);` from stdio.h to Qt::Key?

Tags: c++, qt, char, keypress, getchar

Basically what I am looking to achieve is

```
void getCharSlot(int ch)
{
    switch (ch) {
    case Qt::Key_Escape:{dostuff();}
    case Qt::Key_Tab:   {dostuff();}
    }
}
```

Is there a relatively convenient way to do this?

Comment: What char corresponds to Qt::Key_Escape?

Comment: @eyllanesc `Key_Escape = 0x01000000,`

Comment: `Key_Escape` doesn't fit inside a `char`, what does the `char` contain?

Comment: How to get the value of `c` ?, I think you have a  [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @SombreroChicken its `return getchar();` -- declared from stdio.h --- which now that I look at it, is actually an integer. The code I copied happened to be converting it to char, although Im not sure that matters.

Comment: `getchar()` returns what's typed in, not the keys pressed. Those are 2 different things. (shift, capitals etc)

Comment: @SombreroChicken yes, but my code is flushing after every input, so only a single `keypress` or whatever is registered.

Comment: @Akiva -128 <= char <= 127 and 0x01000000 is not a char

Comment: @eyllanesc yeah. I realized that `getchar();` was being converted from an `int` to `char` -- Not sure if I should delete this question, but we will see.

Comment: @Akiva On the other hand, why do you want to use the Qt::Key?

Comment: @Akiva `char` is a reserved word, you do not use it. On the other hand could you answer my last comment?

Comment: @eyllanesc I build all libraries as api's, so its important to preserve existing api code. I would rather not have to recreate an enumerator for keypresses.

Comment: @Akiva Unfortunately you will have to do it, there is no correspondence between both values. :-)

Comment: @eyllanesc actually, I think I got it to work. After realizing that int was being converted to char,  `const QMetaEnum &keyEnum = QMetaEnum::fromType<Qt::Key>(); QTextStream(stdout) << keyEnum.valueToKey(ch)<<endl;` where ch is the integer returned from `int getchar(void);` seems to be giving me the right output, all except lower case letters.

Comment: Qt use the keys but they are not standard so some may correspond but others may not.

Comment: @eyllanesc No, it actually seems that the lower case letters are not included in the `Qt::Key` enumerator... I wonder why?

Comment: because the Qt developers consider it unnecessary, the information if it is uppercase is indicated in the QkeyEvent not in the Qt :: Key. Look for reasons why one thing or another is done if the code is not based on a standard or protocol that has clear rules, so the answer to your last question is: The Qt developers think it is unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

This question pretty much answers itself actually. I originally posted it without realizing that

```
extern int getchar (void);
```

from `stdio.h` was having its type `int` converted into `char` from the code I copied over.

After removing that conversion, and sending the integer straight to my function below, this worked properly:

```
void Foo::bar(int ch)
{
    const QMetaEnum &keyEnum = QMetaEnum::fromType<Qt::Key>();
    QTextStream(stdout) << keyEnum.valueToKey(ch) << endl;
}
```

Meaning that `ch` will work on an enumerated switch statement.

Comment: This will work for some characters, but not for all. The windows Keys are **not** identical to the Qt keys! And sadly, there is no easy way to map them

Comment: @Felix All have worked for me, and I use a highly customized keyboard layout where just about every last character is rearranged and on different modifiers. I do not however use windows (nor would I ever care to), but I am curious whether you actually tried this?

Comment: Simple example: the charcter `e` does not map to `Qt::Key_E` - only the uppercase `E` does. This goes for all lowercase characters and there are many more. It might work for some, but won't for all